What would be the best way to model topiary?
I'm new to Blender and there seems to be all types of add-ons to look into - has anyone done something like this?
I haven't been able to find a tutorial online other than one written over 10 years ago...
john

hello, model the shape and use particles to create the leaves?

Topiaries seem like something that could easily be achieved easily with builtin features like particle systems or even geometry nodes. Which part do you feel needs an addon? Could you rephrase your question into solving an issue rather than point you to some link?
